# Nested call to integral fails

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, integral, function-handle

Try this piece of code, which works fine.

```
a=1;b=2;
% A two-variate function 
f2= @(x,y) x+y;
derivedF2=@(x) integral(@(y) f2(x,y), a,b);
% Test the evaluation of the derived function handle
derivedF2(0);
% Test the integration of the derived function handle
% integralVal=integral(derivedF2,a,b);
% integralVal=integral(@(x) derivedF2(x),a,b);
% Test plotting of the derived function handle
figure(11);
ezplot(derivedF2);
```

But if you uncomment the lines starting with integralVal. The code breaks.

Apparently, the derived function handle does not support integration operation, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: you should add the `'ArrayValued'` option:

```
integralVal=integral(derivedF2,a,b, 'ArrayValued', true);
```

**Explanation**

You should read your error message:

> Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the 'ArrayValued'
>   option to true.

Because `derivedF2` is evaluated in a vectorised way, i.e. it evaluates `f` at different `y` coordinates at once by supplying a `y` vector instead of a single scalar, MATLAB is unable to evaluate the outer integral in a vectorised way too. Therefore you should add the `'ArrayValued'` option to the outer integral, i.e.:

```
integralVal=integral(derivedF2,a,b, 'ArrayValued', true);
```

Note that `ezplot` also generate the following related warning:

> Warning: Function failed to evaluate on array inputs; vectorizing the function may speed up its evaluation and avoid the
>   need to loop over array elements.

Note that the problem is purely related to nested calls to `integral`, also the following code will result in the same error:

```
integralVal=integral(@(x) integral(@(y) f2(x,y), a,b),a,b);
```

**What is an [*Array Valued*](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#input_argument_d0e495282) function?**

> ... a function that accepts a scalar input and returns a vector, matrix, or N-D array output.

So, `@(y) f2(x, y)` is an array valued function if `x` is an array, i.e. it returns an array for a scalar input of `y`.

Two possibilities exist to avoid array valued problem:

- *Avoid that `@(y) f2(x, y)` is an array valued function*, i.e. avoid that `x` is an array. This can be done by indicating that `derivedF2` is an array valued function as elaborated above, although - strictly speaking - it is not an array valued function, i.e. the integral should have the same number of outputs and inputs. However, it uses internally an array valued function, i.e. `@(x) f2(x, y)` is an array valued function as Matlab evaluates by default the integrand in a vectorised way, i.e. it uses a vector for `y`.
- *Tell Matlab that `@(y) f2(x, y)` is an array valued function*:

  ```
  derivedF2=@(x) integral(@(y) f2(x,y), a,b, 'ArrayValued', true);
  ```

  This may be a more intuitive approach, but is slower as the internal integral is called much often than the external integral.

An alternative interpretation of *Array Valued* is that you tell matlab to not use vectorisation, but for this interpretation the name *Array Valued* is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Thank you very much, @m7913d.  And for the rest of you reading this answer.  One way to fix the ezplot warning is to change that line of code to: "ezplot(@(x) arrayfun(derivedF2,x));"

Comment: Hi @m7913d, as I look more into the "ArrayValued" option, I got more confused. [This link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#inputarg_fun) reads that "If you set the 'ArrayValued' option to true, then fun must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size.".  And [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#input_argument_d0e495282) reads that "Set this flag to true to indicate that fun is a function that accepts a scalar input and returns a vector, matrix, or N-D array output."

Comment: And 'ArrayValued', true indicates that the integrand is an array-valued function.  It makes wonder what on earth "an array-valued function" is...  Sorry if this is too basic a question to ask.